# Executing SQL commands as nested loop of SQL command

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am building a function that uses a SQL query to get a list of tables to drop. Then I want to iterate through each resulting row and execute the command.

```
Public Shared Sub DropTables(DbConnectionString As String)
    Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(DbConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'DROP TABLE ' + name + ';' from sysobjects where name like 'SM_%' and type='U';"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection
    sqlConnection.Open()
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If reader.HasRows Then
        Do While reader.Read()
            Using nonQuery As SqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand()
                nonQuery.CommandText = reader.GetString(0)
                nonQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        Loop
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No rows found.")
    End If
    sqlConnection.Close()
End Sub
```

My issue is that I am getting an this error on this line: `nonQuery.ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
```

But I am using a different data reader.

Comment: are you sure the message is not `There is already an open DataReader associated with this CONNECTION`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against nesting database connections.  Granted, for this purpose I'm sure you're not getting so many results back that you'll exceed the connection limit, but it's generally bad practice.

You're better off returning a List of the table names that you want to delete.  Then, AFTER you dispose of the initial connection (with which you got these table names), you can loop through the table names and create your drop table commands.